# Hole in the engine of John Deere riding mower

Tags: lawnmower, john-deere

How costly would it be to fix a John Deere riding mower that has a hole in the engine? Can the hole be repaired or must the engine be replaced?

Comment: If the hole wasn't there from the factory, the engine will need to be replaced.

Comment: I agree with cory, but it is also important to know is **WHY** is there a hole in the engine. If you don't know, you need to find out. Last thing you want is to get a new engine and have the same results.

Comment: I was with a friend to weld a v8 cast iron block that had a square pushed out by ice - no antifreeze was the cause. engine was fine after... as per the other comment - what was the cause?

Comment: @solarmike Did you weld a frost plug port shut? Seems a little extreme ;)

Comment: Can you post a photo of the damage?  Multiple angles are desirable!  Thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: "a square"  - obviously not a port, this was a square of cast iron (already mentioned) that was between casting webs. A photo is not possible as the car and work was done some 30 years ago... But welding repairs are done every day.

Comment: In addition to welding, there's a technique known as stitching (http://www.doityourself.com/stry/how-to-fix-a-cracked-engine-block) that can be used to fix a cracked block.